# Formatting data so it can appear as a List indicator in AGOL Dashboard

Tags: arcgis-online, list, arcade, dashboard

Below is an example of what My List element looks like in AGOL Dashboards
[image]

My data exists in individual cells and is seperated by ';'. I am trying to get the List indicator to show that after every ';' you would have a new line so an actual list would appear.

How do I write the script that would represent this as a list?

The layer column that I am using is "$datapoint["HF_Number_Type"]"

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want a simple replace function. This Arcade snippet shows how to replace the semi-colon with a new line character

```js
var test = "Cat;Dog;Wombat;Luke Skywalker";
var test2 = replace(test,';',TextFormatting.NewLine);
return test2;
```

You should explore the Arcade API help and you can test your code in the [playground](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/playground/). If you look at the help it clearly states that *Multi-line labels are NOT supported in the ArcGIS API 3.x for JavaScript nor in the ArcGIS Online map viewer*. So a dashboard indicator may not be able to support such formatting, I simply do not know as I've not tried it.

Comment: Appreciate the reply. But yeah I have tried many ways around this and to no avail. Your reply was as far as I have gotten with the arcade expression.